# How can I write a code in Update() that calling once but checking every frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
{
    if (playerPointInt == 1)
    {
        pp1();
    }
}
```

My code is doing ==> if playerPointInt == 1 call pp1 every frame.

I want to do ==> if playerPointInt == 1 call pp1 for one time.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best way to do it in Unity, but a simple fix would be to set a boolean field to `true` when `pp1` is called and then never call `pp1` once that field is `true`.

```
bool pp1_called = false;
void Update()
{
    if (playerPointInt == 1 && !pp1_called)
    {
        pp1();
        pp1_called = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would flip the two conditions to make it more efficient: `if(!pp1_called && playerPointInt == 1)` if the first condition is already false it doesn't have to check `playerPointInt` but can directly skip the code

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code inside the Awake() function which is called when the object is initialized or the Start() function which is called when the object is enabled.  Both functions are called at most 1 time.

Comment: What the OP was looking for was executing the method `pp1();` only once but constantly checking `if (playerPointInt == 1)` in `Update`

Comment: Agree, but that was not how the original question was phrased so it was hard to tell what the OP was asking.